How keep my laptop on while keeping the lid closed?
I have tried to find a solution for this problem. I ended up with two solutions.

Using Gnome Tweaks
Changing values in /etc/systemd/logind.conf

The problems I faced are… with no.1, it doesn’t works anymore
Gnome tweaks doesn’t have the option to that anymore
And with no.2 is… after I change the value and remove the #, I need to restart by typing sudo systemclt restart systemd-logind
But I can’t
My laptop just freezes after asking me for my login password
